# Torque and angular velocity in a lever

Tags: classical-mechanics

Let's consider a lever with an object with mass $m=1$ with distance $x$ from the fulcrum.
If the lever starts at rest and in a horizontal configuration, then in a $dt$ the object causes a $dv=gdt$, that is a $d\omega=\frac{dv}{r}$.

Now, i put another object with mass $m=1$, at distance $x+a$ from the fulcrum. If the lever starts at rest and in a horizontal configuration, this time $d\omega=\frac{dv}{r(x)} +\frac{dv}{r(x+a)}$. The $dv$ is the same for the two objects since the same gravitational force applies.

Now, i remove the 2 objects and i put a object with mass $m=1$ at distance $x+\frac{a}{2}$ from the fulcrum. Since the torque of this object is equal of the total torque of the 2 precedent objects, I expect that, if the lever starts at rest and in a horizontal configuration, in a $dt$ this object causes the same $d\omega$ of the two precedent objects. Is it correct ?

Comment: Hmm... cat got your tongue? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Fulcrum problem]

Part of your problem is you deploy an $r$ but don't define what it is.

Let's do this systematically.

Initially you have a mass $m$ ($=1$ but that's not important) at distance $x$ away from the fulcrum. This mass exerts a clockwise torque about the fulcrum:

$$\tau=mgx$$

This causes angular acceleration $\dot{\omega}$ about the fulcrum, acc. Newton's 2nd:

$$I \dot{\omega}=\tau$$

With $I$ the inertia moment about the fulcrum. For a mass-less beam, we get:

$$I=mx^2$$

So that:

$$\dot{\omega}=\frac{\tau}{I}=\frac{mgx}{mx^2}=\frac{g}{x}$$

The tangential acceleration $a$ of the mass at $x$ can be found from:

$$a=\dot{\omega}\times x=g$$

Now a second object of equal mass is placed at $x+a$.

The torque now becomes:

$$\tau_1=mgx+mg(x+a)=mg(2x+a)$$

The inertial moment becomes:

$$I_1=mx^2+m(x+a)^2=m(2x^2+2ax+a^2)$$

And $\omega_1$:

$$\omega_1=\frac{mg(2x+a)}{m(2x^2+2ax+a^2)}=\frac{g(2x+a)}{(2x^2+2ax+a^2)}$$

Now we could calculate the tangential accelerations, say $a_{1,x}$ and $a_{1,x+a}$, as above and it is obvious that:

$$a \neq a_{1,x} \neq a_{1,x+a}$$

Now for the last case, where we remove both masses and replace it with one $m$ mass at $x+\frac{a}{2}$.

The torque becomes:

$$\tau_2=mg\Big(x+\frac{a}{2}\Big)$$

$$I_2=m\Big(x+\frac{a}{2}\Big)^2$$

$$\omega_2=\frac{\tau_2}{I_2}=\frac{g}{x+\frac{a}{2}}$$

Again we can calculate the acceleration $a_2$ and it is clear it is not equal to $a$.

**Note** that the simplification of the mass-less' beam is not a requirement, only a simplification. Inertial moments about the same axis are additive.

Comment: Then why Spivak (in its "Physics for Matematicians") says that in [this](https://ibb.co/2ycZthF) picture the 6 gray highlighted objects of mass $\frac{1}{2}$ are equivalent to an object in position A with mass $3$ ?

Comment: Because $6 \times 1/2 =3$, And the combined 'grey' masses have a shared CoG at $A$ so the torques about the fulcrum are the same. But the author makes no mention of inertial moments, and thus acceleration. It's a crappy approach and confusing too... You can calculate the MoI yourself to complete the picture.

Answer (score 1):

The torque might be the same, but the combined mass moment of inertia (MMOI) isn't. So angular acceleration will differ.

To find angular acceleration, the shortcut is

$$ \dot{\omega} = \frac{ \text{(torque about pivot)} }{\text{(MMOI about pivot)}} $$

- Case a) One mass

  [image: case_A]

  $$\dot{\omega} = \frac{x m g}{m x^2} = \frac{g}{x} $$
- Case b) Two masses

  [image: case_B]

  $$ \dot{\omega} = \frac{x m g + (x+a) m g}{m x^2+m (x+a)^2} = \frac{g (2 x+a)}{x^2+(x+a)^2} $$
- Case c) One equipollent mass, but at what distance $b$?

  [image: case_C]

  $$ \dot{\omega} = \frac{g}{x+b} $$

To find $b$ equate case b) with case c) and solve for $b$

$$ b = \frac{a (x+a)}{2x+a} > \frac{a}{2} $$

Comment: Then why Spivak (in its "Physics for Matematicians") says that in [this](https://ibb.co/2ycZthF) picture the 6 gray highlighted objects of mass $\frac{1}{2}$ are equivalent to an object in position A with mass $3$ ?

Comment: Because he is talking about statics and the question was about dynamics.